# react-loadable exception 'expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object'

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-loadable to split my react code. With the basic usage, it function normally, but when I custom the render output, it gets some exceptions as below:

```js
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

And my code is:

```js
function Loading(props) {
  if (props.error) {
    return <div>Error! <button onClick={ props.retry }>Retry</button></div>;
  } else {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}

const PipelineConversion = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('App/Reports/Components/PipelineConversion'),
  loading: <Loading />,
  render(loaded, props) {
    const PipConversion = loaded.default;
    return <PipConversion {...props} />;
  },
});
```

I will appreciate it if anyone give me some help or hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should be passing in a function to the `loading` property. Your `Loading` variable is already a function you need not wrap it in brackets `<>`.

For your case this should work

```
Loadable({
  loading: Loading
});
```

Or using it in a function

```
Loadable({
  loading: () => <Loading />
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the guys who got here because they're server side rendering app (server babel transpiled files) spitting out the error above, it may happen because you are using airbnb babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node without setting `noInterop` to false on `.babelrc` as below:

`{
  "plugins": [
    ["dynamic-import-node", { "noInterop": true }]
  ]
}`